# What is the number of registers in CUDA CC 5.0?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have a GeForce GTX 745 (CC 5.0).

The deviceQuery command shows that the total number of registers available per block is 65536 (65536 * 4 / 1024 = 256KB).

I wrote a kernel that uses an array of size 10K and the kernel is invoked as follows. I have tried two ways of allocating the array.

```
// using registers
fun1() {
    short *arr = new short[100*100];  // 100*100*sizeof(short)=256K / per block
    ....
    delete[] arr;
}
fun1<<<4, 64>>>();

// using global memory
fun2(short *d_arr) {
    ...
}
fun2<<<4, 64>>>(d_arr);
```

I can get the correct result in both cases.
The first one which uses registers runs much faster.

But when invoking the kernel using 6 blocks I got the error code 77.

```
fun1<<<6, 64>>>();
```

> an illegal memory access was encountered

Now I'm wondering, actually how many of registers can I use? And how is it related to the number of blocks?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with the number of registers, but with a bug in your code. If you would like help with debugging please post complete, buildable code. What happens when you check the return status of all API calls and all kernel launches?

Comment: @njuffa in fun1() i've allocated 256KB for the array which would exceeds the limit of registers per block. Why it works ?

Comment: A dynamically allocated array like `arr` is *not* stored in registers.

Answer (score 1):

The important misconception in your question is that the new operator somehow uses registers to store memory allocated at runtime on the device. It does not. Registers are only allocated statically by the compiler. The new operator uses a dedicated heap for device allocation.

In detail: In your code, `fun1`, the first line is invoked by all threads, hence each thread of each block would allocate 10,000 16 bits values, that is 1,280,000 bytes per block. For 4 blocks, that make 5,120,000 bytes, for 6 that makes 7,680,000 bytes which for some reason seems to overflow the preallocated limit (default limit is 8MB - see [Heap memory allocation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations)). This may be why you get this Illegal Access Error (77).

Using new will make use of some preallocated global memory as malloc would, but not registers - maybe the code you provided is not exactly the one you run. If you want registers, you need to define the data in a fixed array:

```
func1() 
{
   short arr [100] ;
   ...
}
```

The compiler will then **try** to fit the array in registers. Note however that this register data is per thread, and maximum number of 32 bits registers per thread is 255 on your device.